Where should I ask a question about how armies fight battles?
I'm interested specifically in asking about why armies are vulnerable if attacked on the flank.

Well, no such site afaik, need to start a Military.SE site for that.

For reasons non-specific to a single army, you could try Worldbuilding.SE. Its scope starts where that of History.SE ends. You might need to tag science-based to avoid fantasy. This will give you answers about how armies could be vulnerable; no real army will actually tell you how it is vulnerable

@FranckDernoncourt I'm guessing it's because the site-recommendation tag asks to be specific about the question one wants to ask. Can you clarify yours, JoeB? Is this about the army of a specific country, of a specific period in time, about a specific country or even continent? What kind of attacks do you want to have considered? &c.

@Joachim - I was asking in a general way. I've read about flank attacks in WWII and in the Revolutionary War. Clearly they're something to be on guard against, but no one ever explains exactly why. I searched online and found some fairly clear answers-- but was hoping there would be something more definitive here. Would someone please close this? I don't know how.

@JoeB This question is on-topic, so it shouldn't be closed. "There is no answer" is not a reason to close a question. (If you really want, you can delete the question, but I'd advise against: the comments here will be useful to other people.)

"but no one ever explains exactly why" Common sense would suggest that it is easier to avoid a blow to the face from someone you can see standing in front of you, than from one who sneaks up on you from the side. Or to avoid the blow from the guy you see approaching from the side when you are already busy fighting the one in front of you. Does that really need further explaining? Simply apply that same common sense to military situation x featuring military device/vehicle y. Unless you are asking about a very specific situation in some war of the past etc.

There does not appear to be any site where that question is on-topic.
Not all topics/questions have a home somewhere on the Stack Exchange network.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/site-recommendation/info.
There might be related questions that could be on-topic at particular sites.  I suggest reviewing the list of sites, such as History.SE, to identify candidates.  Make sure to review their policies and what is on-topic on a specific site before asking there.
